# how to display jquery validation error message inside a span

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following script to validate my form. It is working fine but I am trying to show all the validation error messages inside `<span class="errormsg"></span>` separated by comma instead of displaying them all individually beside each input.

I have very little knowledge in jquery; I don't know how to achieve this. Could you please show me?

Thanks :)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit 
    var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
      rules: {
  customerid: "required",
  date: "required",
  invoiceid: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    remote: "<? echo base_url();?>mycontroller/function" }
  },
      messages: {
    customerid: "Enter your customerid",
    date: "Enter your date",
    invoiceid: {
       required: "Enter a invoiceid",
       minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
       remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
    },
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**My Form**

```
<label>Invoice #</label>
<input type="text" name="invoiceid" id="invoiceid" value="" />

<label  style="margin-left:20px;">Date</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="date" value=""  />

<label  style="margin-left:20px;">Customer</label>
<input type="text" id="customerid" name="customerid" value=""  />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use the `showErrors` option to accomplish this:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $(".errormsg").html($.map(errorList, function (el) {
        return el.message;
    }).join(", "));
},
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bd3zM/

**Notes:**

- Uses [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map) to build up an array of error messages based on the `errorList` argument passed to the function.
- Then uses [`.join(", ")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the above array into one string.
- Places the content inside element(s) with class `errormsg` using [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html).

Comment: You're genius :). I have searched a lot on google before posting this question but didn't find anything. Thanks a lot man for the Notes. :)